# Android hide and removing the image in imageview

Tags: android, imageview

How to remove a image in imageview in android and also how to hide the entire image.

Here I have placed an image in imageview by the below code.

```
answerState1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct);
```

I don't know how to remove or hide the image. Also I am entirely new to android development.

Comment: setBackgroundResource(0) is the best option ..  Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can set the visibility of an image with the following method calls:

```
answerState1.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // hide image (make the view gone)

answerState1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  // make image visible

answerState1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  // make image invisible
```

In UI, you can also do something like the following:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgPreview" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: also niki if you are giving View.INVISIBLE the space of the ImageView component that you created will exist there..

Comment: this is what i have done now.. basically am a iphone developer in iphone we can easily remove the image from image by passing nil. or image.removeimage.. is there any way to do like same here... jeni..

Comment: @niki public static final int GONE 
 This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.. so usually in android, we are using this..VieW.GONE

Comment: @niki you need to remove ImageView object.. is that what you mean

Comment: @jennifer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1366/discussion-between-niki-and-jennifer)

Comment: What's the difference between Invisible and Gone?

Answer (score 2):

try this
 imageview.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

Comment: if i am doing like this na space of the ImageView component will exist right..??

Comment: @nik - Yes....Setting the ImageView to INVISIBLE will still allow the ImageView to occupy space in your UI layout.  Making it GONE will cause the parent holding the ImageView to treat the ImageView like it was never there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `answerState1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` to make view invisible and `answerState1.setVisibility(View.Gone);` to make the view invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
im.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
im.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
```

Comment: Changing the height to 0 could make you want to pull your hair out later....wondering why after you set the ImageView back to visible it's still not visible.