# How to to prevent out of memory exception in Runnable

Tags: android, runnable

```
private class Roller implements Runnable
{
    private long delayMillis;

    public Roller(long delayMillis)
    {
        this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (tv != null)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = 3;
            int n = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            String roll = String.valueOf(n);
            tv.setText("Random number is " + roll);

            if (roll.equals("0")) {
                ibRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_selector);
                ibGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_dark);
                ibBlue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_dark);
                ibYellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_dark);
            }
            if (roll.equals("1")) {
                ibRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dark);
                ibGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_selector);
                ibBlue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_dark);
                ibYellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_dark);
            }
            if (roll.equals("2")) {
                ibRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dark);
                ibGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_dark);
                ibBlue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_selector);
                ibYellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_dark);
            }
            if (roll.equals("3")) {
                ibRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dark);
                ibGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_dark);
                ibBlue.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_dark);
                ibYellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_selector);
            }

            tv.postDelayed(this, delayMillis);
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running the above code in the Activity, after some time I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.myapp, PID: 4601
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12960012 byte allocation with 1400312 free bytes and 1367KB until OOM
      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2453)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2360)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:768)
      at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:133)
      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:344)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
      at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:69)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageResource(AppCompatImageButton.java:69)
      at com.myapp.MainActivity$Roller.run(MainActivity.java:85)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What is the best way to avoid that? The drawables are each about 26KB.

Comment: When you get an OOM error, the problem is system wide.  Its usually not the thing you're allocating now that's the problem (unless its huge), its generally a leak elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Should I post the entire Activity code?

Comment: You need to generate some heap dumps and figure out what's using up your memory.  Memory leaks are generally very hard to debug from code alone.

Comment: I am guessing since the runnable is infinite, I have to do manual garbage collection after each run, to get rid of the memory the drawables are taking up?

Comment: Do you want the Runnable to call itself recursively with `tv.postDelayed(this, delayMillis);`?

Comment: I am trying to generate the numbers continuously

Comment: That doesn't seem like the best way to do that. Can you post the code that kicks off the `Runnable`? Are you sure it's only kicked off a single time? Other than that, try removing `tv.postDelayed(this, delayMillis)` from the `Runnable` and rather kick off a continuous series of `Runnable`s. Make sense?

Comment: `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); tv.post(new Roller(900));` in the MainActivity. The TextView is updated with the new generated number. Kind of makes sense but maybe need clarification :) Thanks.

Comment: Tried removing it and it doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: That helps. So are you _sure_ that you only call `tv.post(new Roller(900))` a single time? Perhaps you should post all that code. Also, if you remove `tv.postDelayed(this, delayMillis)` it should run a single time, right?

Comment: @MarkCramer Yes it runs only once. It is being called once in the Activity and nowhere else. I can post the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129668/discussion-between-si8-and-mark-cramer). Let me know if you are coming to the chat.

Comment: In your manifest file put this android:largeHeap="true" inside <application> tag.

Comment: However I read that it isn't recommend... Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

From the code you have posted, it seems like `setImageResource` is decoding the image resource everytime it is called.

The android documentation for the function call says -

> `void setImageResource (int resId)`
>
> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.
>
> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can
>   cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using
>   `setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)` or
>   `setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)` and BitmapFactory instead.

Since you are calling the function repeatedly, this may be the cause of your out of memory exception if your image resource is very large.

I'll suggest that you keep static copies of the decoded image resources and use `setImageDrawable` instead of the `setImageResource` function call.

You can modify your class to hold static instances of your drawables as shown -

```
private class Roller implements Runnable
{
    private long delayMillis;
    private static Drawable lRedDark = null;
    private static Drawable lRedSelector = null;
    private static Drawable lGreenDark   = null;
    private static Drawable lGreenSelector   = null;
    private static Drawable lBlueDark = null;
    private static Drawable lBlueSelector   = null;
    private static Drawable lYellowDark = null;
    private static Drawable lYellowSelector = null;

    public Roller(long delayMillis)
    {
        this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
    try
    {
    if(Roller.lRedSelector == null)
    {
        lRedSelector = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_selector);
    }

    if(Roller.lRedDark == null)
    {
        lRedDark = getResources().getDrawable(R.R.drawable.red_dark);
    }
    //Load all other drawables here ....
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("ERR","Failed to load drawable - " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    }
```

And then modifying your display code to -

```
if (roll.equals("0")) {
            ibRed.setImageDrawable(Roller.lRedSelector);
            ibGreen.setImageDrawable(Roller.lGreenDark);
            ibBlue.setImageDrawable(Roller.lBlueDark);
            ibYellow.setImageDrawable(Roller.lYellowDark);
        }
```

and similarly.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will test it out when I am at home.

Comment: Thank you but what I ended up doing is make a Runnable method and used a handler rather than the TextView as the post and postdelayed and I dont have the issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to keeping copies referenced is to actually render all of them in each place. Then just change the visibility of the one you actually want to show.

`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

See [Android hide and removing the image in imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662871/android-hide-and-removing-the-image-in-imageview)

Just changing the visibility doesn't require allocating more memory to them.